# Power Query date format

Tags: database, excel, postgresql, powerquery

I am using Power Query to access my PostgreSQL database and filter my data by certain date parameters. However, for one of my database tables the date format is `YYYYMM` (201510).

Is it possible to convert this format to an actual date format?

Answer (score 1):

Power Query recognizes `YYYY-MM` or `YYYYMMDD` as valid date formats, but not `YYYYMM`. Here's a solution inserting a hyphen then changing types:

1. Split the text by number of characters, 4
2. Delete the automatic number type inference step.
3. Merge the columns using a custom separator `-`
4. Change type to date

Here's a simple example:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document("201510
201502"),
    SplitColumnByPosition = Table.SplitColumn(Source,"Column1",Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 4}, false),{"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    MergedColumns = Table.CombineColumns(SplitColumnByPosition,{"Column1.2", "Column1.1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(MergedColumns,{{"Merged", type date}})
in
    ChangedType
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),RIGHT(A1,2),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_date('201510', 'YYYYMM');
  to_date   
------------
 2015-10-01
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I prefer to create a new custom column and delete the original column afterwards. In your case the formula for the custom column would look like this:

```
=Text.Range([DateColumn],0,4) & "-" & Text.Range([DateColumn],4,2) & "-01"
```

After adding the custom column you can change it's format to Date.

For further reference check the M Formula reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt211003.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible. Since you import the value as a number you:

1. Transform your value to text
2. Use the Date.FromText function.

The code to do that is:

```
= Date.FromText( Text.From( 201510), [Format = "yyyyMM"])
```

Even though this is the Date.FromText functions, you can find the different format strings for this here:
https://powerquery.how/date-totext/